# What interesting quirks would occur if Magic was suddenly returned after 200 years

Tags: magic

As the title says, what interesting quirks would occur if magic, having been inoperable for 200 years, suddenly started working again? For example, a fantasy world where some idiot accidentally trapped all the magic in the plain of existance in one object, then some other idiot came along 200 years later and released it.

Now, in this case, magical races with extraordinary lifespan have aged at a human rate, so the current generation has had no actual exposure to magic. Their knowledge is limited to books, stories, legends. In this time, technology has been used to replicate much of what magic provided (construction, ship building, farming techniques), much like a mini-industrial revolution (but no steam power).

Aside from the main effects (which are fun in and of themselves), what interesting *little* things would be noticable?

EDIT:
Magic type is based in the traditional fantasy style, a mix of enchantments, spells and rituals.

By little effects I mean the often overlooked aspects, like using a curse word and actually cursing something. Major geopolitical side-effects are not not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hmmmm This seems a bit open ended because we don't know what realm of magic you are talking about.  Are we talking about stuff like Harry Potter and Gandalf where they chant spells with wands and staves?  Or are we talking about something more like the Force in Star Wars that governs the very existence of all beings?

Comment: This sounds rather broad and could result in a million, equally good, answers. Is there something in particular you would like an answer to focus on? The magic style arms race that would ensue, the competition in production, job losses etc

Comment: Agreed you need to specify what you mean by magic, there are so many flavors of magic out their. What magic can and cannot do and how it is gained or used by people or animals makes a huge difference to the possible answers.

Comment: Added some clarifications

Comment: Please note that the [tag:magic] tag specifically requests detail be added to the question. There are a lot of magic systems, and what is "traditional" can vary from person to person or culture to culture. For example, "using a curse word..." is a specific aspect of the magic system you have in mind that differs from several "traditional" models.

Comment: Perhaps spell-maker would have to speak in more arcane language. The spells were written and used when old-fashioned/out of use words were used. So there could be all sorts of errors in delivery that make errors in what is accomplished.

Comment: I've read a whole series of books that explored this very topic. Sorry, but it looks way too broad now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few ideas of varying effect:

- **Artifacts**: A black-smith's hammer that has been in the family for generations will now make armour which is, for some unknown reason, much much stronger than normal. That tattered old glove your family has been handing around for generations has the punch of ten men. That pestle and mortar kept in a family who own the apothecary now makes more and stronger potions.

  - You could have groups of people who have gone around before-hand trying to pick these up, knowing they were special (but assuming they were just relics for a museum).
- **Runes**: Perhaps traps set in a fort or house by the mage who owned it (and set them to go off if he were asleep or out the house) would now be active and some buildings could be quickly evacuated leaving buildings around the world which few dare to enter (though perhaps they hold some secrets to magic that the old owner left behind).
- **Scrolls**: This depends how your magic is activated but there may be some scrolls which are now religious texts but reading them activates some effects (healing, for example) and could bring about a rise in people following those religions.

I can think of many different things, I'm not quite sure where to stop though. It is basically summed up by "Things people forgot were magic"

Comment: OOO I like your magic scroll as it relates to religion!  That actually is a fantastic idea.  In my answer, I was taking more the lines of children superstition and rhymes as those things are passed down generation to generation and thought how funny it would be to one day wake up and they actually were real.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the edit! Based on your example, there are a lot of cool possible things that could happen.  Take something like a favorite nursery rhyme like ring around the roses.  Though we know the actual origins are from the black plague, you could use this as part of story telling legends that when those words were said, it knocked everyone within a certain vicinity down to the ground.  How many times do kids (and even adults ;)) like to pretend they are doing magic by opening an automatic door by doing certain hand movements or saying certain phrases?  Or pretend they are turning on lights to an automatic timer by saying a certain phrase?  You could make it so things like this end up casting spells or enchantments.  The whole "step on a crack breaks your mothers back" might not actually break your mom's back but maybe paralyzes instead.  Maybe walking under a ladder actually does cause someone to get bad luck.  Tons of superstitions that you could use that if one day magic came back, could all of a sudden make all of those come alive.

A common insult in Shakespeare is "I bite my thumb at you" or "you sack of wine".  You could play around with those.  The biting the thumb at someone in Italian and British old culture would be the equivalent of giving the middle finger.  In your story, this act of biting a thumb at someone could be the opening sequence to a curse.

Calling someone a sack of wine may transform someone into a literal sack of wine.

you said no steam powered industry so I am thinking renaissance/colonial era.  Hope my ideas help some or at least gets the answers started!  I just thought of things as a kid/adult I use to do that I use to pretend to do with magic and applied the thought that what if one day they became real.

Answer (score 3):

Initially you'd have to answer the question of whether this magic is accessible to all or to some, and whether it can be learned or must be innate in an individual. Regardless, the following applies to the initial stages of all the previous scenarios and might help to get you started.

To begin with, there would be people who find their interests suddenly working where before they were not. Assuming the spells and incantations are in a common tongue, willful people with strong and vocal desires would begin encountering new success on an inconsistent basis. Confusion would propagate as those individuals try to hunt for the factor that allowed them to succeed.

Also, in a heavily scientific world, there would be experiments going on for various projects. This would likely be an interesting situation for the initial and accidental use of magic, as there are many physical and logical routines that individuals undergo when performing such experimentation according to the scientific method.

Example: If, by some strange design, the repeated mixing of substances in a certain order generates magical effects by ritual, and/or the repeated speaking of the scientist involves words that would form a spell/incantation, the effects of the mixture would be surprising, and lead to odd scientific conclusions to be drawn. This would be especially true if, up till now, this experimental process was leading a completely different direction. Along this thought process it becomes likely the scientists that have been exploring non-magical approaches to things will most quickly and reliably encounter the new magic process.

Alongside the accidental uses and magical happenings, however, the cost of such magic will have to considered. In traditional fantasy, magical forces generally require a source of power - catalyst, mana, etc. - to drive the magic. Assuming the source of individual magic is the essence of one's self, people that accidentally stumble on this new magic and generate it repeatedly will slowly - or quickly - grow fatigued in a way they are not familiar with. This could lead to sickness, physical injury, or even death depending on the nature of magic and its cost.

The specific effects of the magic will be based on the system you create, but these are some basic scenarios that should apply to almost any system.

Answer (score 2):

The Shadowrun universe is based on this premise, though it is blended with a dystopian future.  Since I love that game, this should be  a fun concept.  You might want to look at game references for inspiration.

Magic is, well, magical.  You would have to decide what restrictions to place on it in order to place it into your world.

For the little things that would bring out the reality of magic, fire is always a favorite. So is telekinetic shaking fragile structures to the ground and knocking stuff off of shelves on to the floor.  Both of those have been done to death.

I have always preferred the Alchemical approach to magic.  Earth, Air, Fire, Water.  The little girl who always has her hair blowing behind her.  the kid who makes the most amazing mud pies, that happen to look like the Taj Mahal.  You can also pull in plants and have the adolescent who happens to always have grass growing around their feet.

The rules for the energy supply for magic are important.  If anyone wants to move technology forward in a magical world, they will have to pay attention to these rules in order to do much of anything.

The effects of magic are only limited by the characters imagination.  The rules would still apply, but once they are know, we can manipulate them anyway we want.  Take the young fire mage who hooks up with a water mage and an earthmage.  They get together and and figure out steam power.  the Water, earth and plant mages improve the kingdoms food supply, or maybe establish a dark forest area of their own, and populate it with fairies.